# Gremlin : AWS Neptune - Get all Leaf Nodes for each Node in the Graph as CSV

Tags: gremlin, graph-databases, amazon-neptune

I have a simple graph that has Nodes which represent duplicate record id in the below form

```
Duplicate Id, Original Id
A,B
B,C
C,D
X,Y
Y,Z
```

The directed graph looks like A -> B ->C ->D and I want CSV result that looks like below that has each Node with ultimate leaf node with no more outgoing edges

```
A,D
B,D
C,D
X,Z
Y,Z
```

The above is a simplistic scenario to explain the problem however actual data will have more complex scenarios like below where I have 24 Nodes from A to X with each node connect to other 23 having 24C2=276 directed edges and for each of the 24 nodes I require the ultimate node that has no more outgoing edges.

```
A,B
A,C
A,D
A,E
A,F
A,G
A,H
A,I
A,J
A,K
A,L
A,M
A,N
A,O
A,P
A,Q
A,R
A,S
A,T
A,U
A,V
A,W
A,X
B,C
B,D
B,E
B,F
B,G
B,H
B,I
B,J
B,K
B,L
B,M
B,N
B,O
B,P
B,Q
B,R
B,S
B,T
B,U
B,V
B,W
B,X
C,D
C,E
C,F
C,G
C,H
C,I
C,J
C,K
C,L
C,M
C,N
C,O
C,P
C,Q
C,R
C,S
C,T
C,U
C,V
C,W
C,X
D,E
D,F
D,G
D,H
D,I
D,J
D,K
D,L
D,M
D,N
D,O
D,P
D,Q
D,R
D,S
D,T
D,U
D,V
D,W
D,X
E,F
E,G
E,H
E,I
E,J
E,K
E,L
E,M
E,N
E,O
E,P
E,Q
E,R
E,S
E,T
E,U
E,V
E,W
E,X
F,G
F,H
F,I
F,J
F,K
F,L
F,M
F,N
F,O
F,P
F,Q
F,R
F,S
F,T
F,U
F,V
F,W
F,X
G,H
G,I
G,J
G,K
G,L
G,M
G,N
G,O
G,P
G,Q
G,R
G,S
G,T
G,U
G,V
G,W
G,X
H,I
H,J
H,K
H,L
H,M
H,N
H,O
H,P
H,Q
H,R
H,S
H,T
H,U
H,V
H,W
H,X
I,J
I,K
I,L
I,M
I,N
I,O
I,P
I,Q
I,R
I,S
I,T
I,U
I,V
I,W
I,X
J,K
J,L
J,M
J,N
J,O
J,P
J,Q
J,R
J,S
J,T
J,U
J,V
J,W
J,X
K,L
K,M
K,N
K,O
K,P
K,Q
K,R
K,S
K,T
K,U
K,V
K,W
K,X
L,M
L,N
L,O
L,P
L,Q
L,R
L,S
L,T
L,U
L,V
L,W
L,X
M,N
M,O
M,P
M,Q
M,R
M,S
M,T
M,U
M,V
M,W
M,X
N,O
N,P
N,Q
N,R
N,S
N,T
N,U
N,V
N,W
N,X
O,P
O,Q
O,R
O,S
O,T
O,U
O,V
O,W
O,X
P,Q
P,R
P,S
P,T
P,U
P,V
P,W
P,X
Q,R
Q,S
Q,T
Q,U
Q,V
Q,W
Q,X
R,S
R,T
R,U
R,V
R,W
R,X
S,T
S,U
S,V
S,W
S,X
T,U
T,V
T,W
T,X
U,V
U,W
U,X
V,W
V,X
W,X
```

Here is a graphical visualization using Neo4j - [image: Visual Graph]

For the above case each Node A to W will have X as the ultimate Leaf Node.

There will also be Cyclic loops which I need to avoid in the overall solution. It may be too much to have everything in one step however will appreciate guidance.

**Update : 2020-10-15**
Traversal Optimization need to optimize execution in finding Path from starting Node to Leaf Node

For the Data Scenario below, The result for Vertex A and B should be

```
A,G
A,H
B,G
B,H
```

[image]

The shortest path from A to G is A->C->E->G ; is it possible to suppress any further traversals from A to G when any 1 shortest path to a leaf node is found ? else it will lead to unwanted execution especially for larger clusters of connected Nodes. This steps needs to be repeated again from A to H whose path will be A->C->F->H and then prevent any further attempts to find paths between A and H.

Thanks

Comment: Are you implementing a versioned storage system where in your example "B" is a previous version of "A"? Can you list out a more complicated graph showing what you mean by multiple leaf nodes and cyclic loops? In general cyclic loops are not idea to deal with in graphs, but perhaps your situation calls for it. You should strive to do this in a single step, aside from simpler and more performant code, this will also preserve the ACIDe guarantees of Neptune.

Comment: One additional clarification question. Are you asking how to write a Gremlin query that will generate the second set of pairs you show in the question? If so it would be helpful if you could include some sample Gremlin `addV` and `addE` steps that build a small graph that is representative of your use case.

Comment: Context: The id's are Primary Keys that correspond to Customer Profiling data. The first record means, record A is a duplicate (based on complex criteria) of B (same Customer) so delete A and keep B. Duplicates are identified in Pairs by a system that takes a dataset and returns combinations of duplicate records within the dataset. Business Rules define which of the 2 records in a duplicated pair should be kept and which to be deleted. With regard to multiple leaf nodes ; I could have data like A->B->C->D & A->B->E in which case A has two leaf nodes; D,E (no more outgoing relationships)

Comment: What this functionally means is there is no clarity on which of the duplicate records should be kept, it's either D or E. The final dataset will be used to clean up data from external system that takes id of 2 records and deletes one & retains the other optionally copying data from the deleted record into retained record where the retained one is missing values for attributes.  If the system processes B,C deleting B and keeping C and then finds A,B ; it will try to delete A and update B and will fail when B does not exist so I have to identify the ultimate Node that each Node will fold into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you have provided, the following graph can be built.

```
g.addV('A').as('a').
  addV('B').as('b').
  addV('C').as('c').
  addV('D').as('d').
  addV('X').as('x').
  addV('Y').as('y').
  addV('Z').as('z').
  addE('dup').from('a').to('b').
  addE('dup').from('b').to('c').
  addE('dup').from('c').to('d').
  addE('dup').from('x').to('y').
  addE('dup').from('y').to('z').
  iterate()
```

and the following query used to find the results

```
gremlin> g.V().
           repeat(out().simplePath()).
           until(__.not(out())).
           path().
             by(label).
           local(
             unfold().
             union(
               limit(1),
               tail()).
             fold())


==>[A,D]
==>[B,D]
==>[C,D]
==>[X,Z]
==>[Y,Z]
```

**UPDATED Oct 11th 2020**

Using the larger data set you provided, I tweaked the query a bit so that for each starting vertex only one path to a leaf is found. This runs very quickly. Without doing this, starting at say 'A', there are literally millions of unique paths that end up at 'X' which is why the previous query becomes so complex.

```
gremlin> g.V().
......1>   local(
......2>     repeat(out().simplePath()).
......3>     until(__.not(out())).
......4>     path().
......5>       by(label).
......6>       limit(1)).
......7>   local(
......8>     unfold().
......9>     union(
.....10>       limit(1),
.....11>       tail()).
.....12>     fold())

==>[A,X]
==>[B,X]
==>[C,X]
==>[D,X]
==>[E,X]
==>[F,X]
==>[G,X]
==>[H,X]
==>[I,X]
==>[J,X]
==>[K,X]
==>[L,X]
==>[M,X]
==>[N,X]
==>[O,X]
==>[P,X]
==>[Q,X]
==>[R,X]
==>[S,X]
==>[T,X]
==>[U,X]
==>[V,X]
==>[W,X]
```

Purely for interest the following query shows the highly connected fan out of the graph.

```
gremlin> g.V().group().by(label).by(local(out().label().order().fold())).unfold()

==>A=[B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X]
==>B=[C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X]
==>C=[D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X]
==>D=[E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X]
==>E=[F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X]
==>F=[G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X]
==>G=[H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X]
==>H=[I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X]
==>I=[J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X]
==>J=[K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X]
==>K=[L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X]
==>L=[M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X]
==>M=[N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X]
==>N=[O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X]
==>O=[P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X]
==>P=[Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X]
==>Q=[R, S, T, U, V, W, X]
==>R=[S, T, U, V, W, X]
==>S=[T, U, V, W, X]
==>T=[U, V, W, X]
==>U=[V, W, X]
==>V=[W, X]
==>W=[X]
==>X=[]
```

and the counts (multiplying out those numbers gives a large number) which explains why finding all paths from 'A' is an expensive query. Note that the `simplePath` step helps us by making sure we do not follow any cycles. The number of paths from any vertex to 'X' in this data set ends up being 2^(C-1) where C is the number in the list below for a given start.

```
gremlin> g.V().group().by(label).by(local(out().count())).unfold()

==>A=23
==>B=22
==>C=21
==>D=20
==>E=19
==>F=18
==>G=17
==>H=16
==>I=15
==>J=14
==>K=13
==>L=12
==>M=11
==>N=10
==>O=9
==>P=8
==>Q=7
==>R=6
==>S=5
==>T=4
==>U=3
==>V=2
==>W=1
==>X=0
```

Comment: Many thanks for your response. I am having about 24k Vertices and about 26k edges. My Neptune server with 250GB Mem and 64 CPU's is unable to execute the above query and I ensured there are no cyclic loops so I am need to further refine it. I also tried limiting to a single cluster of 24 nodes linked to each other with a total of 24c2 edges, yet the query continues to run for ever. g.V('0012K00001heOMhQAM').repeat(out().simplePath()).until(__.not(out())).path().by(label).local(unfold().union(limit(1),tail()).fold())

Comment: What happens if you replace the `until` step with something like a `times(3)` as a simple test? If that works, try `times(4)` etc. How deep is the path from there to all of the possible leaf nodes?

Comment: Max depth is 24

Comment: Are you able to update the question with a slightly larger data set? It is hard to know what the issue might be without seeing the data. If that is not possible you may want to open a support case or post to the Neptune support forum so that a support engineer can assist you.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I updated the question with larger dataset. When I run your query against a single cluster of 24 nodes, it takes too much time so I am guessing we can optimize by limiting the 2nd hop to pick a Node that is not connected to starting Node ex- In the data with 24 Nodes as given in the question the Paths to evaluate for A should be ; A -> B/C/D...X [23 options for 1st Hop] -> X [exclude all nodes that are directly connected to A] . Repeat the same for all 23 Nodes. Hope this is making sense.

Comment: Hi Kelvin, could you please take a look at the updated question. Many thanks

Comment: I will take a look. Thanks for providing additional data. It might be better to make this a new question as the original answer solved the original question and this is quite a bit of a step up from that question. I'll make a script to turn your data into a graph and take a look.

Comment: I updated the answer based on what I observed using your larger data set.

Comment: The Result looked amazing, just 1 last issue that still exists, the query is limiting to the first leaf node found starting from any vertex which does not handle the case if the input had 2 more Nodes [X,Y] and [X,Z]. In this case, query starting from Vertex A will result in [A,Y] or [A,Z] but not both and I cant predetermine the max number of leaf nodes. I am guessing if alien level intelligence is needed to tweak to handle this case especially for a map of size as in this example. I am sorry to add complexity but dont have a choice as real world data can show up in all forms and shapes.

Comment: for a Novice, your book "Practical Gremlin" helped me a lot to take the first steps. @Kelvin Lawrence - If you feel my case requires me to study specific sections of this book - please guide me to relevant sections.

Comment: At this point the question has morphed quite a bit from the original which I have provided a couple of answers for. Perhaps it would be best to create to a new question and include a new sample data set made up of `addV` and `addE` steps that create the graph to be analyzed given these additional requirements.